# Came across ApkProvisionException in android studio when trying to run file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I downloaded the file from this [link](https://github.com/pillarpond/face-recognizer-android) and when i try to run that in android studio, the error occured

`Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: The currently selected variant "debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 1 split apks are compatible with the current device with density "420" and ABIs "x86"`

I have not change any of the gradle and travis files. I only did gradle sync. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Ever find a solution?